# iPod touch, 4th Gen. iHome IP90

Tags: ipod-touch, lightning

I bought a iHome IP90 off a friend for really cheap, and I thought I got a deal. Once I tried to use it my iPod wouldn't connect unless I tilted it towards me, and sometimes it would would say that it wasn't supported. I just would like to know if there is anything I can do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I was going to suggest a phone restore and then wondered as to how you could do that if the phone would not turn on or charge. The last fix in the attached link below describes connecting the phone with the USB sync cable to your Mac and then entering DFU mode which you may not have tried.

Comment: Did you mean to include a link?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the correct insert for your iPod in the iHome, all the issues just sounds like a bad connection between the iPod and the dock connector on the iHome, but to what extent this is a bad connection depends on how much time you are willing to spend looking at the issue.

If you don't have the correct insert, find one and try again otherwise...

This could be one of two things in the main:

1. There is/are faulty (intermittent) connections in the dock connector on the iHome that are re-made when pressure is applied to the connector.  This primarily can only be resolved by repairing/replacing the dock connector on the iHome
2. The pins on the dock connector on the iHome or tarnished or faulty in that they no longer make a full electrical connection to the pins inside the iDevice. Pressure on the iDevice remakes this connection.

The not supported message is usually a message shown when a single pin in the dock connector does not get a signal. As the iPod line aged, some pin functions were removed (such as the power charging pin change that was introduced with the iPhone 4).

You have three options I think

- try and clean the dock connector on the iHome to see if resolves the issues
- purchase an apple dock extender cable that **might** make a better connection
- replace the dock connector on the iHome